# Why Does This Sentence Use Present Continuous instead of Present Perfect?

Tags: present-tense

I **am releasing** a new xxxx single. It is very limited I only pressed only 100 Copies.  You can order it

Why 'am releasing' because the record has been pressed and ready to be ordered. I would have used present perfect  have released

Comment: _Please always give the source of your quotations!_ I would assume that the official release date hasn't arrived yet. People are sometimes invited to place orders in advance of publication.

Answer (score 1):

The simple present in English makes it seem like you are narrating a story, announcing something, or describing your actions in realtime to an audience, unless:

- the verb means *possess*
- the verb is a copular verb (*be*, *seem*, *look*, *smell*, etc.)
- you're describing a habitual action and this is usually accompanied by words or context that describe how often (I walk there everyday).

If not one of the above, it sounds awkward and unnatural unless you use the *be + X-ing* form.  You normally want to use the *be + X-ing* form to talk about something you are doing in the present.

This is in contrast to other languages like Spanish where you would use the simple present.

Answer (score 1):

Because the writer is referring to the whole process of creating, marketing, and distributing the media as "releasing", not just the creation; so the *releasing* is still going on.

Answer (score 1):

We often use the present continuous/progressive tense to talk about the future. The future actions and events are already decided. They are planned, or they are starting to happen.

**I am releasing**...= I have arranged to release...(**I pressed**/I have pressed...)

We can also say 'I am going to release...'

'I am releasing' and 'I have released' have different meanings.

'I am releasing' (NOT completed action)-  I have not released yet.

'I have released'(completed action)

So 'I have released' is incorrect. 'I am releasing' is correct.